# Execute function on callback

Tags: vue.js

I am utilizing a payment component that uses a callback function to show whether or not the payment was successful I am trying to execute a function in that callback method that tells the backend that payment was complete with some details.

Sample of component

```
              <component
                :amount="amount"
                :ref="ref"
                :callback="processPayment"
                :close="close"
              >Proceed to payment</component>
```

Payment callback method

```
processPayment: res => {
//window.alert("Payment recieved");
    
this.postPayment(res); // <-- this does not execute.
}
```

Any ideas how I could get it to work ?

Comment: You should use events. See an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-williamson-d3v3z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with `this`.

`this` in arrow function does not refer to the owner of the function, rather arrow function takes `this` from it's context, which will not be the Vue instance

So, avoid using arrow functions as Main methods in Vue component. You can use arrow function as callback.

```
processPaymentfunction(res){
//window.alert("Payment recieved");
    
this.postPayment(res); // <-- this will execute.
}
```